# Rspec is it possible to do something like should_receive(:foo).with(:bar).and_call_original.exacly(1).times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, matcher

Is it possible to do something like `ServiceObject.should_receive(:foo).with(:bar).and_call_original.exacly(1).times`?

My specs look something like this:

```
it 'should call instance of service object\'s :baz! method' do
  ServiceObject.any_instance.should_receive(:baz!).exactly(1).times
end

it 'should call service object\'s :foo method' do
  ServiceObject.should_receive(:foo).with(:bar).and_call_original.exacly(1).times
end
```

If I remove `and_call_original` the first spec fails. If I comment out the `.exacly(1).times` in the second spec both specs pass.

Two questions:

- Why do these two specs interfere with one another?
- Is there a way to call something that means `.should_receive(:foo).with(:bar).and_call_original.exacly(1).times`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`and_call_original` doesn't return the current `example` so it cannot work.

Instead you can do:

```
.should_receive(:foo).with(:bar).exactly(1).times.and_call_original
```

Comment: Haha... should have tried that. For some reason I was thinking .times wasn't returning the example. Thanks!